# Facebook new search API - how to get the list of fans?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, facebook-fql

This topic has like a hundred threads, but since facebook has now new searching API, I am creating another thread that is connected only to the new API.

**I know that getting the list of page fans was impossible before**

**Question 1**:

Did facebook along with his new search API introduce anything new for developers that would allow to get a list of fans via http/json/oauth ? (  I didn't notice anything on their dev/website )

**Question 2**:

It is possible to scrape

`https://www.facebook.com/search/{page_id}/likers`

or

`/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/BrowseScrollingSetPagelet?data={querystring}`

without asking user for his password (via OAuth)? (the site won't let unauthorized users).

**Would such action violate `TOS` ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1

Facebook does not have a new search API. Facebook has a Graph Search which is not related to their current search API at graph.facebook.com/search?q=

Question 2

It is possible to scrape the page given the right parameters for headers and cookies (which are only obtainable with an active user session to Facebook)

For other users this wouldn't work, if it did I believe this would be a cross site request, which Facebook prevents with anti-csrf tokens.

I'm not sure which section of the TOS or developer policy states it, but I'm pretty sure building an application out of it will get your application banned and/or your IPs from which you scrape blacklisted or even a cease and desist for unauthorized mass scraping.